# How to find size of blob in different access tier inside an azure storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

The requirement is to identify the size of Hot access tier blobs and archive access tier blobs in a storage account for analysis regarding the cost. How can we calculate this total size of Azure Blobs?

Answer (score 5):

Was able to find out a way to fix this :) Sharing as it might help others.

Open the storage account and select 'Metrics' blade. Scope will be automatically selected as the storage account. Now select 'Metric Namespace' and choose 'Blob'. In the 'Metric', choose 'Blob Capacity'. Now click on 'Apply Splitting' and select 'Blob Tier' as the value.

This will provide the blob capacity separated by blob tier from azure portal.